# Функция atoi

Tags: c, c++

Проблема вся в том, что atoi преобразует мне строку из цифр в коды таблицы ascii. К примеру, если строка = "7", то он мне преобразует эту строку в число 55, если число однозначное, то, конечно, можно вычитать 48 и все совпадет. Но если число двухзначное, то так уже не сделать. Дальше приведен кусок когда где я это использую.

```
void ReadListP(int* masP, char* cListP, int sizeP)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char temp[100]="";
    char str[100]="";
    char symbol=',';
    for(int j=0; j<=sizeP; j++){
            if(cListP[j]!=symbol){
                sprintf_s(temp, "%d", cListP[j]);
                strcat_s(str,temp );                
            }
            else{
                sprintf_s(temp,"%d",str);
                masP[i]=atoi(temp);
                sprintf_s(str,"%d","");
                i++;            
            }
            j++;
        }
    masP[i]=atoi(str);
}
```

Что-то читал про использование юникода, но так и не понял, при чем тут это... Кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не так делаю?

Comment: @Максим Игнатьев Уважаемый участник, вопросы на форуме должны качественно оформляться: http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/04/blog-post_22.html

Comment: В чем чуть? Что нужно получить? Массив чисел из строки?

Comment: p.s.: код нужен сишный или с++шный?

Comment: p.p.s: какие ограничения на входные данные?

Comment: спасибо большое я уже разобрался с данной проблемой, а суть была что бы преобразовать char в числовой массив. В char входят цифры и запятая.

Answer (score 3):

Это потому, по-моему, что вы вот тут (temp, "%d", cListP[j]) переводите символы в их коды (%d - трактовать аргумент как целое число), которые с помощью atoi превращаются обратно в числа =D
Смотрите неправильно работающий код в отладчике - там такое видно.

То есть, вы неправильно разделяете строку на элементы. К слову, сделать это можно гораздо проще и без таких загогулин с пользованием sprintf и strcat.

Comment: Спасибо большое учту замечание. А если вместо "%d" ставить "%s" то тогда он считывает как символ же? Но так вылетает ошибка, точнее break.

Comment: sprintf(my_str, "%s", x); // распечатать x как строчку (<b>s</b>tring); x - типа char*<p>
sprintf(my_str, "%i", x); // распечатать x как целое число (<b>i</b>nteger); x - int, long int, short int, char и т.д.<p>
%d дает тот же эффект. d - от <b>d</b>ecimal (десятичное)<p>
sprintf(my_str, "%c", x); // распечатать символ с кодом указанным целым числом x (<b>c</b>haracter); x - int, long int, short int, char и т.д.<p>

Comment: Рекомендуемые ссылки:<p>
1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc(v=vs.71).aspx<p>
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Ну, для начала, Вы с аргументами sprintf_s() напутали. Не понимаю почему не ругается компилятор.

Должно быть sprintf_s (char *result_buf, int bufsize, char* format [, аргумент]...)

Если допустить, что где-то есть #define sprintf_s sprintf, то становится ясно (по крайней мере для одного единственного символа '7' в cListP[0]).

В sprintf_s(temp, "%d", cListP[j]) (на самом деле, как я понимаю sprintf()) Вы записываете в temp cListP[j], как десятичные цифры (для "7" получим "55") а потом добавляете эти "55" в str. После цикла в str как раз и будет "55".

Так что atoi(str) работает правильно !!!

Comment: Черт, после char звездочки пропали. А ведь набирал.

Comment: Их заэкранировать надо: \\\* =)

Comment: Можете вы мне немного уточнить я пользуюсь VS 2008 так вот когда просто sprintf то он мне выдает warning а когда написал sprintf_s то все нормально...в чем разница этих функции тогда?

Comment: По поводу sprintf() и sprintf_s() пояснить не могу. sprintf_s() впервые увидел у Вас (что это такое посмотрел в Google). Я пользуюсь gcc, в винде он в MinGW.

Comment: разница простая. sprintf стандартная классическая функция.  есть везде, где есть си. sprintfs -  расширение crt для повышения безопасности. принимает доп.аргумент - длину буфера, куда все пишется. т.е. это весьма ломовой способ избежать ошибок типа переполнение буфера

Comment: Вообще-то интересный вопрос, почему у автора sprintf_s() (с такими аргументами (см. код в начале)(размера буфера нет)) компилируется?

Comment: Потому что автоматом подставляется sizeof(buf), точнее countof(buf). Существует несколько вариантов реализации этих функций. См. заголовочные файлы.<p>
Доп. инфа по ссылке http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175759.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1.

```
/* допустимый вход - числа, разделенные символами ,.- 
   если изменить delim в аргументе strtok - можно изменить символы-разделители
   например, добавить буквы :-)
   Также ф-ция не проверяет размерности аргументов.
   Предполагается, что cLisP - стандартная 0-terminated C-string,
   а masP - указывает на массив int'ов, причем заведомо бОльший, чем необходимо    */
void ReadListP(int *masP, char* cListP)
{
    char *pch;
    pch = strtok(cListP, ",.- "); // вытаскиваем первый токен до разделителя
    while (pch!=NULL) // пока есть токены
    {
        sscanf(pch, "%i", masP++); // запихаем очередное число в массив.
        // вместо sscanf легко применить atoi
        pch = strtok(NULL, ",.- "); // вытаскиваем следующий элемент строки
    }
}
```

Вариант 2.

```
/* допустимый вход - любой поток символов
   ф-ция выдерет все числа из этого потока
   т.е., например, "fdsfds2324" будет обработано как десятичное 2324.    */
std::string x;
int n;
std::getline(std::cin, x, '\n'); // получим строчку до символа перевода строки
std::stringstream y(x); // сделаем удобную штуку - превратим строчку в поток
do
{
    y>>n; //ВНИМАНИЕ! atoi не нужен! как и sscanf! Все делает operator >>
    std::cout<<n<<" "; // выведем число для отладки на экран
    if (y.fail()) // если облажались с выборкой числа и получили что-то несусветное,
    // в n пишется 0 и устанавливает флаг ошибки.
    {
        y.clear(); // очищаем флаг(и) ошибок
        y.ignore();// снимаем с буфера один символ
    }           
}
while (y.good()); // пока есть дата
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь мне подходит первый вариант так как пишу на win32 api. Так как я не очень понимаю в программирование то так бы не догадался сделать.

Comment: А еще посмотрите на strtol(), часто ей удобно выбирать в цикле целые числа из строки символов. И тщательно тестируйте свою программу, подавая на вход разные (казалось бы немыслимые) комбинации правильных и ошибочных данных. По сути, Вы должны определить для себя (желательно достаточно формально) язык, представляющий входные данные, а также варианты обработки ошибок в них.

Comment: <i>подавая на вход разные (казалось бы немыслимые) комбинации правильных и ошибочных данных.</i><p>
Скажем так - это нужно, но не нужно фанатеть. Дело в том, что если у меня серьезный программный комплекс, а числа, например, считывается из файла конфигурации и происходит сбой, что формат вводимых данных некорректный, то нужно обязательно в первую очередь показать сообщение об ошибке. А то возможно или файлы побились полностью и программа считает бред, или пользователь ввел в файл какую-то недопустимую комбинацию. И что он подразумевал - неизвестно.

Answer (score 1):

Прекратите гонения на atoi(), она работает как надо и не надо к ней никаких фиксов писать: atoi("7") == 7