# Как распарсить входной поток данных без использования Boost

Tags: парсер, потоки-данных, c++

Как я могу распарсить входной поток данных (не файл) в C++. Т.е., например, на каком-то этапе выполнения программы пользователю предлагается в консоли ввести строку (целиком, не через Enter), а потом мне её нужно, после того как нажали Enter, распарсить по числам (int).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно легко обойтись средствами стандартной библиотеки,
например используя string streams:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    cout << "Input numbers: \n> ";
    getline(cin, input);
    vector<int> numbers;
    istringstream is(input);
    int tmp;
    while (is >> tmp)
    {
        numbers.push_back(tmp);
    } 
    cout << "You have entered " << numbers.size() << " numbers" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Внимание - есть недостатки!

Comment: Ну так напишите, какие недостатки вы видите.

Comment: `while (is >> tmp)` - эта фраза меня сбивает с толку.
Да и трасса выполнения программы такая:

<pre>gaal@linux-lybs:~/EULER> g++ blabla.cpp 
gaal@linux-lybs:~/EULER> ./a.out 
Input numbers: 
> 1 2 3 
You have entered 3 numbers
gaal@linux-lybs:~/EULER> ./a.out 
Input numbers: 
> 1 2 3 fdfdf 32 
You have entered 3 numbers</pre>
Т.е. работает не совсем корректно (а именно - считывает числа до первого "не числа")

Comment: Проверка в while - это стандартная возможность istream-ов, если она смущает можно посмотреть документацию.
Этот пример не претендует на правильную обработку любых входных данных, он просто показывает направление в котором надо искать решение.

Answer (score 4):

Если внимательно посмотреть ответы на нижеприведенные вопросы, то сможете сами составить корректную программу для считывания чисел.

- [Перевод string в integer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12292/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-string-%D0%B2-integer)
- [Небольшой анализ правильности ввода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16019/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)
- [Как считать массив типа int из текста?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/22501/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-int-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)
- [Функция atoi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16477/%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-atoi)
- [Вопрос об оптимальности парсинга строки вида ...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/15797/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-r142c1543-r18999c24568)

Обязательно следует обратить внимание на формат вводимой строки. Какие символы там допустимы? Надеяться на то, что пользователь в 100 из 100 случаев будет вводить корректную строку глупо. В результате программа упадет или будет некорректно работать. Поэтому думайте как производить проверку корректности ввода (если, конечно, это не студенческий проект или есть гарантии того, что на входе будет всегда корректная комбинация символов).